# Rasa webchat integration - 3.0

Tags: socket.io, integration, chatbot, rasa

I'm are developing a bot using rasa open-source (3.0) , I want to integrate this AI bot to my website . I tried it using the bot widget provided by the official document ,still whenever I give inputs to bot it didn't respond .
however all the responses get printed on rasa console(which means no problem with socket connection).
So how can I solve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HWP1.png)

I try integrating the rasa bot to website and expecting the bot will reply to user input but it didn't respond to any input given[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUzcB.png)